# "Filter as you type" a large table (>100K rows)

Tags: database, search, text-search, content-filtering

I have a large table (>100K rows) that looks like this:

```
     Movie       |      Genres
--------------------------------------------------
Inception        | Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi
The Dark Knight  | Action, Crime, Thriller
The Godfather    | Crime, Drama
```

I'd like to filter the table as I type.

Performance: Until recently, I didn't think it's possible with a table of this size, but [Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_(software)) is able to filter as I type over 1M files on my hard drive.

Filtering: Ideally, I'd like to have keywords. For example, `m:dark AND g:cr` would return all movies where one of the genres contains `cr` (Crime, in this case) and the title contains `dark`. And so on.

Comment: I've never seen anything that can do this without major performance issues, and if the table is hosted on SQLServer on a network resource, the performance goes down from there. Is there some specific reason that you want filtering done this way?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: The table will be hosted locally (on an SSD). I just wanted the tool to be more dynamic. I really like searching with Everything, it's a nice experience to see it filtered as I type.

Comment: postgresql fts is probably an easy option for you. or a search engine like elasticsearch